# Why CameraCaptureUI always shows a circle crop?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, camera

In early 2018 I coded an app using UWP and I used CameraCaptureUI to take pictures. I left most options as default including the AllowCropping which is set to true.

After clicking on the camera button the UI gave the option to crop the picture. Then, the picture could be cropped in a rectangle. However, I opened the app to do some fixes a few days ago and now the crop is a circle.

Here is what I see now:

[image: a busy cat]

I already tried using the CroppedAspectRatio property to make the crop UI use a 4:3 rectangle, and it didn't work.

This is the original code:

```
cameraDialog.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
var file = await cameraDialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

And this is what I tried and didn't wort:

```
cameraDialog.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
cameraDialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);
var file = await cameraDialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

The CameraCaptureUI doens't have many options. So I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

> Why CameraCaptureUI always shows a circle crop?

In last version we have some updates for crop UI, I tried use the circle crop UI to crop picture, the cropped image is correct size as previous setting `CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3)`. I discussed with related team and report this behavior. Currently we have work around that is disable  `AllowCropping` property(default is true).

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;           
StorageFile file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

And you could also custom camera with `MediaCapture` class and this is [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame) that you could refer

Comment: Nico, did you open an issue in GitHub or something similar? I'd like to know the outcome and if needed provide details about my environment.

Comment: I have reproduce this issue  in my current environment and reported this issue  to related team, if there are any updates I will post below.

Comment: @AlexHerrera Please post your issue on the feedback hub and paste above case link, our team will take and process it .